# Parabolic subgroups of $\mathrm{Sl}_n$ are the ones that stabilize some flag

Tags: matrices, reference-request, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I am looking for a reference for the above statement that every parabolic subgroup of $\mathrm{Sl}_n(\Bbbk)$ stabilizes some flag in $\Bbbk^n$. I have gone through a large pile of books and can't seem to find one. Thanks a bunch in advance!

**Edit:** I understand $G=\mathrm{Sl}_n(\Bbbk)$ as a connected algebraic group and define a parabolic subgroup $P\subseteq G$ to be one that contains a maximal connected solvable subgroup. I know how this is equivalent to $G/P$ being complete (or projective).

Comment: Is this not the definition of parabolic subgroups of $SL_{n}(\mathbb{k})$ or are you using the definition of a parabolic subgroup being the normalizer of a radical subgroup?

Comment: I would use the definition that the group contains a maximal connected solvable (i.e. Borel) subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Books on "buildings" will discuss such a definition/theorem, in the example of $SL_n$, for example, my book that is also on-line, "Buildings and Classical Groups" (see http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/buildings/). In fact, this idea is what Jacques Tits was trying to abstract for exceptional groups by his more general notion of "building".

Comment: That's sweet - could you tell me the chapter/section, or even better, the page number?

Comment: Chapter 9 of my book is exactly about "the spherical building for GL(n) (or SL(n))". Starts on page 131.

Comment: Thanks this looks good. I like that you also have the symplectic group worked out explicitly.