# Clarifications about parabolic subgroups of $GL_4$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm asked to find all the parabolic groups $P$ which contains $T_4$, the subgroup (borel) of upper triangular invertible matrices. This is my definition of parabolic subgroup

> Let $P$ be a subgroup of $G$, then $P$ is parabolic iff $G/P$ is a projective variety.

Over the internet ( for example [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101b/parabolic.pdf)) I found another definition of parabolic group of $GL_n(k)$ which is:

> $P \leq GL_n(k)$ is parabolic if stabilises a flag in $k^n$.

I'm not so practical with this notion, can someone explain me the equivalence of this two definitions?

Comment: a subgroup is parabolic iff it contains a Borel subgroup (see e.g. Milne's notes on algebraic groups). Obviously, a group stabilizing a flag contains a Borel group. The other direction is shown in the linked file.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but I think $k$ at here is assumed to be algebraically closed. Then $G/P$ is a projective variety implies that $G/P$ is a complete variety, whereas later is equivalent to $P$ is any subgroup between $G$ and $B$, since $B$ is the minimal subgroup with this property. Note that for semisimple algebraic groups, $G/B$ is in fact a flag variety, so we cannot get any smaller ones. The part that $G\supseteq P\supseteq B$ implies $P$ acts as a stablier for a certain flag is proved in the file you linked.

Also this one seems largely a duplicate of this question:

[Parabolic subgroups of $\mathrm{Sl}_n$ are the ones that stabilize some flag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184999/parabolic-subgroups-of-mathrmsl-n-are-the-ones-that-stabilize-some-flag?rq=1)

Comment: Why the down-vote? Can someone explain (or simply write a better answer to replace it)?

Comment: I did not down voted sorry. I'll start reading the answer right now

Comment: the point is that I did not want to use that theorem, because I've never seen the Bruhat decomposition, anyway I try to follow that reasoning

Comment: @LuigiM: Try the pdf file in the other link then. I think Paul's treatment is fairly readable.

Comment: do you mean around page 137?

Comment: @LuigiM: Yes, I only took a glimpse of it, but as I have read some his other notes, I believe his writing should be helpful (to an average grad student like me).